# sas how to count items in a list

Tags: macros, sas, counting

I would like to count the number of integers in my variable, the same way that %countw counts the number of words in a variable.

Example:

```
%let  test = 'aaa' 'bbb';
%let ntest = %sysfunc(countw(&test.));
```

ntest = 2..
My question is how to do this for integers?

Now I have:

```
%let test2 = 12, 13, 14;
```

How to get ntest = 3?
How can I get the number of items in &test2.?

I apologize if this is ridiculously simple and I just missed the documentation.

Comment: This works: **%let ntest2 = %sysfunc(countw("&test2.", ',' ));** I think SAS understands commas as command separators in countw function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are commas as delimiters in your macro variable value, you can use the `%superq` function to prevent these commas to be interpreted as parameter separators in the macro call. And since your values are separated by both commas and spaces, you can specify both in a `%str` function, for the same reason as previously.

```
%let test2= 12, 13, 14;
%let ntest=%sysfunc(countw(%superq(test2),%str(, )));
```